# All user lost permissions including system account

Tags: 2010, permissions, user

All users have lost all the permissions on the site collection. Even the System account can not perform any action.

I have reviewed the services and profile sync is correct.

[image: System Account lost all the permissions]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Content DataBase was in read-only mode for any problem with an update.